# Custom Scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: scrollbar]

How is it possible to create a custom scrollbar in Android, one that will live outside a list/scrollview. I am at a lost, and hoping that you guys can throw a lot of ideas at me ;)

Answer (score 0):

To change the image you can simply do this in your `style.xml` and apply it in your `ScrollView`:

```
<style name="your_style_name">  
  <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarStyle">outsideOverlay</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
  <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scroller_thumb</item>
</style>
```

where scroller_thumb is your custom image for the scroller thumb.
For the rest (`up` and `down` views) you can use photoshop or something like that.

Hope it helps you